# Training neural networks to learn moving averages

Tags: neural-network

I am training a neural network to learn to calculate moving averages. The input is 5 day values and the output is moving average of the 5 days. But the NN is unable to learn it. It is giving a constant value for all predictions. The code is given below.

```
X_train = []
y_train = []
n = 2000
for i in range(5, n):
    X_train.append(df.iloc[i-5:i, 0])
    y_train.append(df.iloc[i-1, 2]) 
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 250, batch_size = 32)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try autoregression?

Comment: The objective is to understand the workings of neural networks.